# Need to play an mp4 file before actual website

Tags: web, mp4

Hi I want to play an mp4 file on when some one visits the website and than load the actual website when video ends.
How should I do that, I will be glad if someone will tell me the logic rather than code.
It will be only for the main page if some one is coming from the search engine to inner page than he should see the inner page rather than the video

Comment: The 1990s called, and they want their Internet back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For ***search Engine*** First check the visitor from where he is come from `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` and after then redirect him to the main site
And if the visitor is come directly or not matches with the search engines then :

1. Get the actual play time to video. like minutes
2. throught javascript redirect the page to the Main website.

in the second point i choose javascript case it will provide you the facility to reload the page or redirection after a time period..

Comment: well I figured out a hole... video will take time to download which will be different for different user so I don't think fixing a delayer time will be good